# Maven-antrun-plugin 1.4 doesn't send anything trough ftp

Tags: java, maven, ftp

So I installed this plugin for sending file through ftp. Unfortunately I have to use this version. Here's code in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ftp</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <ftp action="send"
                                 server="10.132.30.179"
                                 remotedir="subsystems"
                                 userid="radio"
                                 password="oss"
                                 depends="yes"
                                 verbose="yes">
                                <fileset dir="C:\Users\Michal\Downloads\web-framework">
                                    <include name="*.txt"/>
                                </fileset>
                            </ftp>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And everything works just fine when I invoke 'mvn package'. Package is build and there are no errors. But nothing goes thourgh ftp. Here's what I get on this stage in build.

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.4:run (ftp) @ dist ---
project.artifactId
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Does the fileset resolve to a non-empty set of files?

Comment: yes, I created some files right there just for this task

Comment: Does the fileset task agree with you?

Comment: In what sense? I mean whole build ends as success.

Comment: The behavior you see is consistent with having an empty fileset so there are no files to send and nothing is done.